# How do i mirror along grid aix using mirror modified?

Tags: mirror

The mirror modification is not mirroring along the x axis like i wanted, it is doing this:

[image]

Can sb please help me?

Comment: Two things. One, your object is not at the worldspace origin. Technically, it isn't absolutely necessary that it be, but for now, just start with it there, and keep it there, before continuing with modifiers. It will make your life easier. Two, your View tab is showing in the Properties Shelf. If your Item tab was up instead, we could see what the transform coordinates are of your base object, which I suspect were not applied before beginning your modifier. Apply all transforms before beginning a mirror modifier.

Comment: Hi R-800, 1st solution is no go; i moved the object to world origin, then applied mirror, still the same issue. 2nd solution is also no go; all transformation have been applied...

Comment: Share your file. https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: I also believe that transforms haven't been applied as otherwise Mirror modifier mirrors along global axes which is not the case on the screenshot. Select object in Object mode > ctrl+a > rotation to make sure it was

Comment: thanks everyone, i just did the dumbest work around: ctrl-D in object mode, then rotate the duplicate, and then joining them...works but troublesome. I couldn't share the file...since it has already been overwritten...